# Issues with the "after" method in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a memory game in Python Tkinter. After a card is flipped, I'm using the after method to make the reset function in my code delay for one second before the card is flipped back. It makes the function just wait forever. Can someone please explain why it's doing that?
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Disney Princesses Memory Game")
width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
screen.configure(bg="#e0bce5")

title = Label(screen, text="Memory Game", font=("David", 50, "underline", "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
title.place(x=400, y=20)

images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/aurora.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/belle.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/cinderella.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/jasmine.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/mulan.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/rapunzel.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/snow white.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/tiana.png")
]

buttons_list = []
chosen_images = []
flipped = []
num_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
card = PhotoImage(file="images/card.png")
count = 0
no_press = False


def choose_images():
    for num in range(16):
        chosen_image = choice(images_list)
        num_list[num] += 1

        if num_list[num] > 2:
            num += 1
            continue
        else:
            chosen_images.append(chosen_image)


def replace_card(c, d):
    global flipped, count, no_press

    if no_press is True:
        return

    count += 1

    if count > 2:
        count = 0
        no_press = True
        sleep_secs()
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[d])
        flipped.append(buttons_list[c][d])


def reset():
    global card, no_press
    for element in flipped:
        element.configure(image=card)


def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    screen.after(1000, reset)
    no_press = False


choose_images()
x = 100
y = 250
for i in range(2):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
        a = Button(screen, image=card, command=lambda i=i, j=j: replace_card(i, j))
        x += 100
        a.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(a)
    y += 100
    x = 100

screen.mainloop()
```

The weird thing about the after method for me is that it worked when I implemented it in a smaller program:

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("600x800+30+10")
hi = Label(screen)
hi.place(x=20, y=20)


def reset():
    hi.configure(text="hi", font=("Ariel", 30))


def sleep_secs():
    screen.after(2000, reset)
    print(2)


sleep_secs()
screen.mainloop()
```

What's the deal with that?

Comment: Can you explain what just making part of a program sleep means?

Comment: tkinter has its own async "call this other function in N seconds" mechanism. You should use that rather than any of the generic, non-tkinter-aware answers thus far given. (This kind of situation is part of why we have the close-as-duplicate mechanism, to guide folks to somewhere the set of available answers is already comprehensive, and where those answers have already had the benefit of comment feedback, voting, etc)

Comment: @Scott Hunter, it means delaying the program by a couple of seconds

Comment: @Charles Duffy, can you make an answer and show me how to implement it?

Comment: @Roni Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method). I think @ CharlesDuffy is talking about the `.after` method. But be careful: the first argument is in milliseconds.

Comment: @Roni Try [this](https://pastebin.com/8ep6mFCP)

Comment: It helped in one way, but then introduced me to a new bug. The program waits for more than the amount of seconds that I put in "sleep"

Comment: @Roni, even `time.sleep` is allowed to sleep for longer than you ask it to. Only real-time operating systems guarantee to get back exactly when expected. OTOH, if it's a _substantial_, reproducible difference on an unloaded system, that might be worth a Stack Overflow question with a reproducer showing how to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: oh, so what should I do?

Comment: Really, I'd ask a question with a [mre] that measures and quantifies how the `.after` approach in tkinter is delaying much longer than it should. It's a new and different question, and a worthy one.

Answer (score 1):

Try with async function:

```
from random import randint
import time
import asyncio


async def randn():
   await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return randint(1, 10)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I’m not very familiar with the async function. Can you explain to me what’s the use of “return randint(1, 10)”? Why do we need to return a random integer between 1 and 10?

Comment: It's just an example, replace it with the core of your function.

Comment: I don't think this would work...Could you be more specific?

Comment: @MhamedBendenia Please add an explanation to how the code in your answer works. It isn't going to help OP if they don't understand it. If OP uses your code but doesn't understand it, it can make their program undebuggable.

Comment: It doesn't work. The error: C:\Users\Meirom\PycharmProjects\memorygame\main.py:62: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep_secs' was never awaited
  sleep_secs()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: can you please show me how to do it with my code?

Comment: @Roni I have no idea how `asyncio` works but does it use another thread/process to run the code? If it does, then you should call `tkinter` functions from `asyncio` because `tkinter` isn't threadsafe and some times it can just crash.

Comment: I didn't use threads. I'm pretty much a Python beginner/almost intermediate, so I'm not familiar with threads yet

Comment: My bad. I wanted to tag @MhamedBendenia on my last comment.

Comment: Sorry for the fuzzy answer @TheLizzard, here you can find all what you need regarding asynchronous functions : https://www.aeracode.org/2018/02/19/python-async-simplified/